# Connecting LED to just positive

Tags: power

My question is, why does this work:

[image]

But not this:

[image]

My best guess is that since the motor draws current, it forces electrons through the LED as well. But then, this doesn't work:

[image]

I'm not an electrical wiz clearly, if there's a simple explanation, I'd appreciate it.

I usually think of electricity as water moving through a pipe, with the pressure being voltage and amount of water being current. I understand this is not an actually accurate way of thinking about it.

Comment: Case 1, the LED drops 2 V (about) and leaves the remaining 7 V (about) for the motor. It's a series circuit so the motor and LED will experience the same current. The other cases are nonsense because the LED is wired wrong. However, in case 2, you could wire it correctly and get the LED to operate. The CR20xx series batteries can't supply a lot of current so avoiding the current limit resistor can work in that specific case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep in mind that on a normal breadboard all five holes in a row (in this case row 7) are shorted together.

In your second and third pictures, no significant current will flow in the LED because both leads are shorted together.  It's much easier for the current to flow through the metal strip in your breadboard than through the LED, so nearly all of them do.

Comment: You're definitely right, that explains it. I forgot about resistance . Hence even if you recreated the example with wires, it still wouldn't work since the wire would have a lower resistance than the LED. I'm an idiot. Thank you !!

Comment: I assume my original idea was also correct. Positive and negative terminals don't need a direct connection as long as they are in the path of electron flow (and the flow is in the correct direction).

Comment: @zapshe Correct.  You can connect the LED through the motor, or a resistor, or many other kinds of devices.  In fact, you should be doing this.  Connecting an LED without something (usually a resistor) to limit the current is likely to burn it out.